# Sending Email with attachment from Parse.com

Tags: ios, image, email, parse-platform, email-attachments

I am working on my first IOS app which will be displayed in a public place where a user can draw an image and send this image to an email adres. I don't want to use Mail for this and the image also can not be stored on the iPad. 
Therefore, i use Parse.com to store the image including name and email adres.

Now, i need to make a simple interface to send all the emails to the correct email adres including the image. We would like to check the image an email adres before sending. So i was thinking of showing some sort of tabel, with the image, name and emailadres and a send or delete button. So with a quick click we can send the image.

Now I don't know where to start!

What is the most easy way to do this? Making a second IOS app where all the images will be shown and can send/delete from? Using Mailgun and Cloud Code?
Or true a web-base interface? Using PHP?

I am all very new to this, so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Parse integrates with mail services like Mandrill so you can send e-mails from there using cloud code.

You need to have some users in the system, or some store of user details at least, then you can upload the images. Look at using a class for images, where the class just has a single `PFFile` and a relationship to a user.

Now, in your app you can display images and the associated user info. When hitting the 'send' button you would call a cloud function with the image `objectId`. The cloud code can use that to find the image, it can use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` to get the data for the image from the `PFFile`. Once you have that you can create your e-mail and send it.